# Php file upload code not working properly in ubuntu using mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to upload my file to database and display the same. but it is not working .. I also give permission to my folder where the file is to be uploading. couldn't understand what's wrong with this code.
my HTML and PHP code is given below .please go through it and helps to solve my issues.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Image Upload</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="uploadedFile">
        <input type="submit" name="upload">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
    class fileUpload {
        public $uploadedFile;
        public function dbConnection (){
            $this->connectDb = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "spawoz","student");
            if ($this->connectDb->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $this->connectDb->connect_error);
            }
            echo "Connected successfully";
        }
        public function upload (){
            if(isset ($_POST['upload'])){
                $this->target_dir = "/var/www/html/php-pgms/images";
                $this->target_path = $this->target_dir . basename ($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);
                if(move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'], $this->target_path)) {  
                    $this->sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO fileupload (namefile) VALUES ('$this->uploadedFile')";
                    $this->result = mysqli_query ($this->connectDb,$this->sqlQuery);
                    if ($this->result == true)
                    {
                        echo "File Uploaded";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public function displayImage (){
            $this->query=  mysql_query ("SELECT namefile FROM fileupload");
            $row=  mysql_fetch_array ($this->query);
            echo "<img src='images/".$row['namefile']."' height = '130px' width = '130px'>";
        }
    }
    $obj = new fileUpload();
    $obj->dbConnection ();
    $obj->upload ();
    $obj->displayImage ();
?>
```

Comment: You're saving `$this->uploadFile`, but I can't see you actually setting that property anywhere?

Comment: u mean $this_>uploaded file? that is my input feild

Comment: I understand what it _suppose_ to contain, but since you never set that property anywhere, it will be empty (containing `null`). You need to actually give it the value you expect it to contain.

Comment: i changed that line to $this->sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO fileupload (namefile) VALUES ('$this->target_path')";echo $this->sqlQuery;          still its not working

Comment: Then why did you accept the below answer if it didn't solve your issue?

Comment: actually that is also needed to get the out put .i set that one one also.iam new to here .i dont know the procedures

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: but why ? i just doing this in my local server

Comment: Because it's better to always write secure code. If you always do it, you can reuse your "local" code for real projects without needing to rewrite it to be secure. If you even remember to do it at all. There's also the issue that if the values would contain, for example, a single quote `'` the query would fail. It would be something like: `column = 'I'm foobar'`. See the issue? SQL would read the `'` in `I'm` like the closing quote for the value. There are more characters and cases that could mess up the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I Just change the line $_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name']    to $_FILES["uploadedFile"]["tmp_name"]

Answer (score 0):

Please add the backslash for the target_dir variable as like :

```
$this->target_dir = "/var/www/html/php-pgms/images";
```

Replace by

```
$this->target_dir = "/var/www/html/php-pgms/images/";
```

Also please check the permission of the "images" folder.

Comment: i tried that also .but not working.my code give result up to th emove_uploaded_file line

Comment: It also won't solve the issue posted in the first comment under the question. Also, those aren't back slashes, they are forward slashes, but yes, there should be a trailing slash. :-)